# How to fix 'Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference' when calling getParent() method

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, nullpointerexception

I have button inside LinearLayout which is part of cell in RecyclerView. I want to change it to another button so I use some method which require button's parent view by calling button.getParent() method. Unfortunately it ends with 'Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewParent android.view.View.getParent()' on a null object reference' error. I feel like I miss looking something, but I can't catch what it could be. I'll be grateful for your help.

In Code Samples below I include code that, in my opinion, is crucial to solve my problem. Of course I can provide more, if needed.

layout_cell.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="2dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/subItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/descript"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttonsLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/fileNameTextViewInCell"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="8dp"
            >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/downloadButtonInCell"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:icon="@drawable/ic_download"
                app:iconPadding="8dp" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>




</RelativeLayout>
```

CellAdapter.java:

```
public class CellAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CellAdapter.ViewHolder> {

      @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View view = LayoutInflater
                    .from(viewGroup.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.layout_cell, viewGroup, false);
            mViewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
            return mViewHolder;
        }

    viewHolder.mDownloadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {

                        ViewGroupUtils.replaceView(view, mViewHolder.mLoadingButton);

                        view.setEnabled(false);

               }
           });

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;
            Button mDownloadButton;
            Button mLoadingButton;
            LinearLayout mButtonsLayout;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mRelativeLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
            mDownloadButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.downloadButtonInCell);
            mLoadingButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.loadingView);
            mButtonsLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonsLayout);

        }
    }



}
```

ViewGroupUtils.java:

```
 public class ViewGroupUtils {

    public static ViewGroup getParent(View view) {
            return (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
    }

    public static void removeView(View view) {
        ViewGroup parent = getParent(view);
        if(parent != null) {
            parent.removeView(view);
        }
    }

    public static void replaceView(View currentView, View newView) {
        ViewGroup parent = getParent(currentView);
        if(parent == null) {
            return;
        }
        final int index = parent.indexOfChild(currentView);
        removeView(currentView);
        removeView(newView);
        parent.addView(newView, index);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are dynamically trying to remove the existing button from the recyclerview row and replace it with a new view, just a suggestion can you try this option

have the existing view in visible state and new view in hidden/gone state and based on the logic just flip the visibility of both the existing and new view?

so first by default --> 
Existing View --> state VISIBLE

New View --> state HIDDEN/GONE based on your requirement

so based on your condition

Existing View --> state HIDDEN/GONE
New View --> state VISIBLE

This might be easier and you might not have to struggle with the recycler view as the next challenge would be to get the dynamic id for specific row.